# Calculo de um valor a elevado a um expoente b

Tags: java

Devo criar um algoritmo que faça o calculo de um valor a elevado a um expoente b.
É um exercício que não pode usar o Math.pow. Fiz o algoritmo e quando coloco expoente negativo o resultado buga.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        int base, expoente, calculo=1;
        System.out.println("Informe a base:");
        base = ler.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Informe o expoente:");
        expoente = ler.nextInt();
        while(expoente!=0) {
            calculo=base*calculo;
            expoente--;
        }
        System.out.println(calculo);
    }
}
```

Sei que é por causa do while que está dando esse erro mas não tenho ideia de como arrumar.

Comment: Se o expoente for positivo, você tem que decrementá-lo até chegar a zero, mas se o expoente for negativo você tem que **in**crementá-lo até chegar a zero. Teste se `expoente` é maior ou menor que zero, e aja de acordo (não se esqueça também que o cálculo em si é diferente para expoentes negativos - `2^3` é `8`, mas `2^-3` é `1/8`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deveria verificar se o expoente é negativo, e se for, inverter a base e trocar o sinal do expoente:

```java
if(expoente < 0) {
    expoente *= -1;
    base = 1 / base; 
}
while(expoente != 0) {
...
```

Comment: +1 só lembrando que pra isso funcionar tanto `base` quanto `calculo` têm de ser `double`s, não `int`s (do contrário, qualquer base maior que um virará zero).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.